# tidyverse stringr() replace string with expression including superscripts & subscripts

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I have a df thus:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tribble(
  ~col1,
  "one",
  "Cab"
  )
```

I wish to replace all instances of `Cab` with `Ca+b`, where `a+b` are subscript.
This works to replace the string:

```
renamed <- df %>% 
      mutate(across("col1", str_replace, "Cab", "Ca+b"))
```

I have tried:

```
renamed <- df %>% 
  mutate(across("col1", str_replace, "Cab", expression("C"[a+b])))
```

But get:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
i `..1 = across("col1", str_replace, "Cab", expression("C"[a + b]))`.
x `replacement` must be a character vector
```

Comment: You can't store expressions along with character values in the same column of a data.frame. Why are you trying to store expressions? Is this for plotting? It would be better to focus on the plotting function itself if that's the case. It's not clear what your ultimate goal here is at the moment.

Comment: `parse()` will enable you to create an expression from text.